# "Almost mean" of a set of integer

Tags: number-theory

I have three integers $(a, b, c)$ (but this can be generalized to any size). I want to redistribute the sum $a+b+c$ as equally as possible between three variables. In our case, we have three cases:

If $a+b+c=3k$, then the solution is $(k, k, k)$.
If $a+b+c=3k+1$, then the solution is $(k, k, k+1)$.
If $a+b+c=3k+2$, then the solution is $(k+1, k+1, k)$.

Does this notion have a name in mathematics?
Any references?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $a,b,c$ has nothing to do with this. Rather, it's a question about $d=a+b+c$. The original values $(a,b,c)$ are irrelevant except for the sum and the number $3$.

Comment: Actually they are relevant is the sense that it is the starting point for the algorithm

Comment: No, $a+b+c$ is the starting point. The individual values, $a,b,c$ are irrelevant to the  question, as indicated by your answer - only $a+b+c$ matters.

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/banff.pdf) explains a slight variant of Euclid's algorithm that solves this problem, and says that these near-uniform distributions occur in traditional musical rhythms.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_rhythm) uses the term "Euclidean rhythm", but maybe that doesn't make sense in a broader context than music.

Comment: I'm confused about what these linked articles have to do with this question, which is an absolutely trivial application of the division algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

From a graph theoretical perspective, there exists a specificly named graph called a [Turan Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) labeled in writing as $T(n,r)$ (the turan graph on $n$ vertices subdivided into $r$ camps).  It has the special property of being the graph with the most number of edges which does not contain a clique of size $r+1$.  As far as I can see, they did not name the process used in separating the integers, but rather spell it out that for $n$ vertices and $r$ camps, there will be $(n~\text{mod}~r)$ subsets of size $\lceil n/r\rceil$ and $n - (n~\text{mod}~r)$ subsets of size $\lfloor n/r\rfloor$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This really is just the "division algorithm." Let $m$ be the sum you want, and $n$ be the number of variables.

Use the division algorithm to write $m=nq+r$ with $q$ the quotient and $0\leq r<n$ the remainder. Then you can write $m$ as the sum of $r$ instances of $q+1$ and $n-r$ instances of $q$.